# Distributing extra space in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to build a `RelativeLayout` which distributes excess space between its children, much as shown here:

[image: RelativeLayout example]

I've figured out how to center the red widget inside the blue one, but what I also want to do is distribute any excess vertical space evenly above, below, and between the blue and olive widgets. Currently, everything is bunched up at the top.

My `XML` looks roughly like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/blue_button"
        android:src="@drawable/blue_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red_box"
        android:src="@drawable/red_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/blue_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/blue_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/blue_button"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/green_button"
        android:src="@drawable/green_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/blue_button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are using `layout_weight` with `RelativeLayout` parent. It's useless because `layout_weight` works only with `LinearLayout` parent.

Actually I didn't understand your question  (an image of wanted layout would be good) but I guess this will work for you:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/blueAndRedWrapperLay"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       >

       <ImageButton android:id="@+id/blue_button"
           android:src="#00CCFF"
           android:layout_width="300dp"
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/red_box"
           android:src="#ff0000"
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           />

       </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/greenWrapperLay"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/green_button"
        android:src="#669900"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, using layout_weight was a shot in the dark. I did provide a crude diagram -- I was just demonstrating that I wanted excess space distributed evenly.

Comment: OK, reading your response -- that's actually exactly what I'm doing now. I was just hoping to reduce complexity a bit and I couldn't shake the nagging feeling that I was missing something.

Comment: Actually using more layout isn't complex. But you should avoid using unnecessary `wrap_content`.  Because it's calculating the size of child layouts when drawing view so it can be a little inefficient sometime.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll keep doing what I'm doing then. What do you mean about "unnecessary wrap_content"? What should I be doing instead?

Comment: I just want to give advice. I meant, when you can give `match_parent` and `wrap_content` to a layout, just give `match_parent` to prevent complex calculation that android does.

Comment: OK, got it. I wrote a calculator app once that had forty buttons plus the display, all inside the same container widget. Every time the display changed (e.g. after every button press), the entire app went through a layout cycle. It was a serious performance killer. After I isolated the display and the buttons in separate container widgets, the unneeded layout calculations went away.